# Bootstrap ToolTip needs double click instead of single click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

If I click on another field with a tool tip, it requires a double click to show the tooltip. I am not sure what part of my code is incorrect. I have referred other Stackoverflow posts, none seem to solve the issue. I am on Bootstrap version 4+

I have placed the following code in (document).ready function

```
function call(){
        console.log('calling tooltip method');
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({placement:"right",trigger:"click",html: true});

    }
    function hide(){
          $('body').on('hidden.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
            $(e.target).data("bs.tooltip")._activeTrigger.click = false;
          });
          $('html').on('click', function(e) {
            if (typeof $(e.target).data('original-title') == 'undefined') {
              $('[data-original-title]').tooltip('hide');
            }
          });
        $(document).on('show.bs.tooltip', function() {
            $('.tooltip').not(this).hide();
        });
```

Comment: have you checked the initial state? if it's target is already set to true/visible, the first click won't do anything

Comment: @oeste can you specify what you mean? I have not initialized in the (document).ready function. Should I initialize?

Comment: Are you using any specific framework or pure js? I lean toward always initializing, but that could just be my preference and not best practice.

Comment: I added $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  to the (document).ready function to initialize. Now, it no longer clicks and shows tooltip, but it acts as a hover. I have not set it as hover property. @oeste